# Could not load file or assembly ‘PdfSharp, Version=1.51.5185.0,The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: pdfsharp, uipath, uipath-studio

I'm making custom activity for UIPath which needs PDFSharp dependencies , i have added the dependencies for the PDFSharp but dont know what to do for assembly reference

this problem is coming with windows compatiblity of the project but not with windows-legacy

here is the metadata code of nuget pakage explorer

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>TiffToPdf.Activities</id>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <title>TiffToPdf.Activities</title>
    <authors>Sagar Raval</authors>
    <owners>Sagar Raval / Jaydeep Lunagaria</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <iconUrl>https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-convert-icon-3209-thumb.png</iconUrl>
    <description>This pakage conatins ConvrtTiffToPdf Actvity which helps convert Tiff files to pdf 

- It supports single and multiple pages</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6.1">
        <dependency id="PDFsharp" version="1.51.5185-beta" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework="net6.0-windows7.0">
        <dependency id="PDFsharp" version="1.51.5185-beta" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```